# TypeORM Data Mapper Pattern - type safety for instantiating new entities?

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings, typeorm

I'm looking for a way to ensure type safety and that required properties are set while instantiating new objects. Using the `<EntityRepository>.create({...})` method complains if you provide properties that don't exist however the compiler does nothing if you fail to provide a required property, ie `<EntityRepository>.create()` happily creates a new object without anything set (no required props).

Is it best practice to add a constructor to the class and that way you can ensure it's created with the correct properties? ie:

```
import { ApiProperty } from "@nestjs/swagger";
import { IsNumber, IsOptional } from "class-validator";

export class FeedbackDTO {
  @ApiProperty()
  @IsNumber()
  rating: number;

  @ApiProperty()
  @IsOptional()
  comment?: string;

  constructor(rating: number, comment?: string) {
    if (!rating) {
      throw new Error('Rating is required');
    }
    this.rating = rating;
    this.comment = comment;
  }
}
```

Alternatively is there some other approach or paradigm that should be applied for this sort of scenario? The situation is we found a small bug where objects were being instantiated but missing required props.